# Graphics2D Drawing Lines to Scale to Create Rects

Tags: java, scale, graphics2d, lines, rect

I am trying to make a fill bucket tool by storing the lines it needs to draw. I have that part working well, but now when I try to scale it, I run into the problem where I have areas that are not drawn in between some of the lines. Is there any way to fix this, or a better way to do this?

This code will demonstrate the problem I am running into. The first square is not scaled and looks fine, but when I scale the second box, there is space in between some of the lines.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class LineWidth extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LineWidth l = new LineWidth();
        l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        l.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for(int i=10; i<110; i++) {
            g2.drawLine(10, i, 190, i);
        }

        Graphics2D g22 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g22.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g22.scale(2.1, 2.1);
        for(int i=120; i<220; i++) {
            g22.drawLine(10, i, 190, i);
        }
    }
}
```

For this example it would be much easier to draw a rect instead of lines, but for my fill bucket, I do not see a way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using an affine transformation instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm trying that now, but I'm not sure what to do differently. I'm doing transform.scale(2.1, 2.1); and I'm getting the same result, which I kind of expected. What part of it should I be trying to change?

Comment: Can you use `Graphics2D.fill(Shape shape);` instead of drawing lines? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill(java.awt.Shape)

Comment: @martini I'm not too familiar with shapes, so I'm not sure. If I could take my list of lines and turn that into a shape than I'm sure that would work well. I'll look into this. Any good places to start?

Comment: @maptwo3 A Polygon is what you need :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

Comment: @martini I'm not sure how that would work because my fill shape won't always be a perfect square, so I would have to somehow find all the outside points, along with the inside points so it doesn't fill something I dont want it to.

Comment: I "think" this has something to do with the scale been a fraction.  If you use whole numbers, it doesn't seem to have problems.  This may come down to rounding issues in the rendering engine.  I would use `Shape` if you can as they tend to scale better...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah that's what I've been seeing as well as I've been looking into it more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up drawing my lines to a `BufferedImage` than I would scale that `BufferedImage` instead of my lines. This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it worked pretty well and it is running fast enough. Thanks for the suggestions on this.